# How to package JS code so it can be called from other programming languages

Tags: javascript, node.js, package

I'm trying to come up with a cross-language way to write a JS function and make it callable from any other programming languages.

WebAssembly through WASI is close in terms of the functionality (it's cross platform and cross language) and but it's obviously not for packaging JavaScript. Basically I'm looking for a solution where I can write a single JavaScript function, compile it into a binary, expose some interfaces, and call it from outside.

Packaging in a Docker daemon as an HTTP or RPC server kind of achieves this too, but it's too heavy because I have to keep Docker running at all times (as well as expect the users to run them) and a persistent server is required.

The most obvious options is to compile them using something like `pkg` and call the program from other languages using system calls, but I'm not sure if using system calls to communicate between languages is a recommended practice. (Is it? And if so, would appreciate some examples)

Are there any "clean" ways to achieve this goal?